# Download all data of shiny datatable

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, datatable

To download a large (>100.000 rows) datatable I set server=TRUE. This however removes the option to download all data.
Following [this](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267) I made a custom download button. Which works for one table. I would like to use two tables which does not work. See minimal working code example below:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
callback <- JS( #for custom download button
    "var a = document.createElement('a');",
    "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
    "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
    "a.download = '';",
    "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
    "$(a).text('Downloadt1');",
    "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
    "$('#download1').hide();"
)
callback2 <- JS( #for custom download button
    "var a2 = document.createElement('a');",
    "$(a2).addClass('dt-button');",
    "a2.href = document.getElementById('download2').href;",
    "a2.download = '';",
    "$(a2).attr('target', '_blank');",
    "$(a2).text('Downloadt2');",
    "$('div.dwnld2').append(a2);",
    "$('#download2').hide();"
)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            box(DT::DTOutput("t1")),downloadButton("download1", ""),
            box(DT::DTOutput("t2")),downloadButton("download2", "")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$t1 =DT::renderDT(server=TRUE,{
        datatable(iris,extensions = 'Buttons',callback = callback,
                  options = list(
                      dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip')
    )})
    
    output$t2 = DT::renderDT(server=TRUE,{
        datatable(iris[,1:3],extensions = 'Buttons',callback = callback2,
                  options = list(
                      dom = 'B<"dwnld2">frtip')
    )})
    
    #download button
    output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("t1.csv")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            fwrite(iris, file)
    })
    #download button
    output$download2 <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("t2.csv")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            fwrite(iris[,1:3], file)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Think the issue lies with the callback or JS code. I would appreciate any help with this.
Thank you!

Comment: `var a2 = document.createElement('a');`, not `var a2 = document.createElement('a2');`.

Comment: Dear Stephane, I changed the code accordingly, however the second table's download button is still not showing up. So your suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: Perhaps because you inverted callback and callback2.

Comment: That did it! I updated the code and it works now. Both tables have a custom download button :D Thank you for your input!